# Is it possible to automate the extract of Apple News / iCloud News Publisher analytics data?

Tags: google-bigquery, icloud-api, apple-news

I'm trying to set up a dashboard in Google Data Studio with Apple News analytics data as one of the sources.

I can see you can download this analytics data manually as a CSV - does anyone know a way of automating this extract? Automatically appending the data weekly to a BigQuery table would be ideal, or Google Sheets or directly into Data Studio if not.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can load your CSV into BigQuery [1], or schedule a load job, and then use it in datastudio through a BigQuery reader package. Otherwise, if you do not need to append the data you can simply import it with other packages as "Custom JSON/CSV/XML" By Supermetrics.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#supported_data_formats